# React Navigation navigate and scroll

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-navigation

I'm using the StackNavigator from react-navigation and I'm trying to customize the navigation process.

On one screen, I have two buttons that both use the "navigate" function to redirect the user to the same screen (which is a scrollview).  Is there any way to have one of the buttons scroll down to a different part of the screen after navigating?